# Choice of PUT/POST in REST for creating multiple resources

Tags: rest

I am aware of a well-known question here: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

However I am a bit confused in one of my case and would want to seek for advise to properly design my RESTful WS:

Assume my system work like this:

My system will have multiple batch jobs defined (e.g. `JOB1`, `JOB2`).

For every day, I will ask my system to create a list of batch job schedule, by providing a specific date (e.g. I passed in 2014-12-25, then system will create `JOB1(2014-12-25)` and `JOB2(2014-12-25)`.

User can trigger a batch job schedule to execute.

I want to seek for advise to proper expose these as resource:

Should I do a POST or PUT to the resource `/batchSchedules` to trigger the creation of `batchSchedules` for a specific date?  How should the URL looks like to make it a proper RESTful API?

What should the "schedule triggering" looks like?

I am thinking of these two choices, but both doesn't sounds quite right to me:

---

Approach 1:

To create schedule for a specific date: `PUT` to `/batchSchedules/2014-12-25` with empty request body, as it seems that I am creating "bunch of schedules" as the resources declared in URL.  (However, it does seems right because I am not going to replace it if I call it again, which doesn't looks quite well)

To trigger a schedule execute: `PUT` to `/batchSchedules/2014-12-25/JOB1` as it seems replacing the batch schedule resources (but it looks strange coz I am not really replacing the resource, cannot take a POST here because I am actually not generating a child resources below the URL)

To get the status of a schedule with meaningful input: `GET` `/batchSchedules/2014-12-25/JOB1`

To get the status of a schedule: `GET` `/batchSchedules?id=12345` which 12345 is the ID for a schedule

---

Approach 2:
To create schedule for a specific date: `POST` to `/batchSchedules` with date in request body, as it seems that I am creating a child resource of batch schedules

To trigger a schedule execute: `PUT` to `/batchSchedules/2014-12-25/JOB1` as it seems replacing the batch schedule resources (but it looks strange coz I am not really replacing the resource, cannot take a POST here because I am actually not generating a child resources below the URL)

To get the status of a schedule with meaningful input: `GET` `/batchSchedules/2014-12-25/JOB1`

To get the status of a schedule: `GET` `/batchSchedules?id=12345` which 12345 is the ID for a schedule

---

Approach 3:

To get the status of a schedule with meaningful input: `GET` `/batchSchedules?job=JOB1&date=2014-12-25`

To get the status of a schedule: `GET` `/batchSchedules/12345` which 12345 is the ID for a schedule

To create schedule for a specific date: `POST` to `/batchSchedules` with date in request body, as it seems that I am creating a bunch of child resources of batch schedules under `/batchSchedules` (doesn't seems quite good)

To trigger a schedule execute: `PUT` or `POST` to `/batchSchedules?job=JOB1&date=2014-12-25` as it seems replacing the batch schedule resources (looks really strange to me)

---

Which of them is the appropriate way of exposing my WS in proper REST manner?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, the client isn't providing any information besides the date to construct the schedule. If that's true, I'm going to argue you should be using a GET, and not a PUT or a POST. Conceptually, there's no reason here for a client to do anything to create a resource - it's all on the server side. All the client knows is "I want the batch job schedule for day X". Whether the server needs to create a new schedule or retrieve an existing schedule isn't something the client should need to care about.

```
GET /batchSchedules?date=2014-12-25
{
    "id": 12345,
    "self": "/batchSchedules/12345",
    "jobs": [{
            "id": 67890,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}

POST /scheduledExecutions
{
    "scheduleId": 12345,
    "date": "2014-12-25"
}
```

The response from the post would either be a `200 OK` if the batch is done immediately, or more likely a `202 Accepted`, along with a `Location` request header for the URI for batch results, something like `/scheduledExecutions/67890`.  Calling a `GET` on that URI would return status information on the batch, possibly including URIs to the statuses of various jobs in the batch.

```
GET /scheduledExecutions/67890
{
    "status": "In progress",
    "date": "2014-12-25",
    "jobs": [{
        "id": 13579,
        "status": "Complete",
        "self": "/scheduledJobs/13579"
    },
    {
        "id": 24680,
        "status": "In progress",
        "self": "/scheduledJobs/24680"
    }
}
```

If I misunderstood, and you're executing jobs, not whole schedules, then you'd have `POST /scheduledJobs` and `GET /scheduledJobs` instead of `/scheduledExecutions`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to further read into it.  Just one thing: I want to avoid using GET in creating those "schedule", because I want the creation to be explicit, and GET /schedules/DATE should give me schedules (that is previous created) of a specific date.  If that's my design decision, how should I expose it in a RESTful way?  And I believe my idea of job schedule is more like your "schedule execution": my "schedule" is a job scheduled to execute for a specific date.

Comment: Well, if you're determined to use PUT/POST, it comes down to the information the client has. If the client can *fully* specify the schedule, then PUT is appropriate. If there's any information that can change which the client doesn't have, you *must* use POST.